# zipcloudのAPIで郵便番号を入れると住所を表示するアプリを作りたい

Tags: swiftui

## 目指していること

https://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search
SwiftUIで郵便番号をテキストエリアに入力して検索ボタンを押すと、住所を表示するアプリを作りたい。
上記のAPIと接続し、て住所を取得する

## 困っていること

シミュレーターを起動してみると検索窓と検索ボタンが表示され、住所をハイフン無しで入力し検索ボタンを押しても何も表示されない。

## エラー

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002184500 'assistantHeight' SystemInputAssistantView.height == 45   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x109133490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000217aad0 'assistantView.bottom' SystemInputAssistantView.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x109133be0.top   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x109133490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000217b8e0 'assistantView.top' V:[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x1091df4f0]-(0)-[SystemInputAssistantView]   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x109133490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000218ac10 'inputView.top' V:[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x1091df4f0]-(0)-[_UIKBCompatInputView:0x109133be0]   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000217b8e0 'assistantView.top' V:[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x1091df4f0]-(0)-[SystemInputAssistantView]   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x109133490 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```